# Spring boot Mongo Reactive Repository issue while saving the document.ERROR:[Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.DBRef]

Tags: spring-boot, functional-programming, spring-data-mongodb, reactive-streams

I've been working upon one spring boot web application where I've decided to use ReactiveMongoRepository to persist data. But while I was saving document I'm observing one exception that I'm struggling with last couple of days to solve it but no luck. The exception is:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a 
codec for class com.mongodb.DBRef. Caused by: 
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a 
codec for class com.mongodb.DBRef.
at 
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46) 
~[bson-3.4.2.jar:na]
```

Please refer below my Code classes and property files:

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-
reactive')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-webflux')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=demo
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private PersonDetailsRespository personDetailsRespository;

@Autowired
private PersonRespository personRespository;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

private void dataBuilder() {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setAge(23);
        person.setName("Jitender");

        personRespository.save(person).subscribe();

        PersonDetails personDetails = new PersonDetails();

        personDetails.setAddress("Address");


        personDetails.setPerson(personRespository.findByName("Jitender").block());


        personDetailsRespository.save(personDetails).subscribe();

}
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    dataBuilder();
}
}
```

Person.java

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Person {
public Person(String id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}
@Id 
private String id;

private String name;
private int age;

}
```

PersonDetails.java

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PersonDetails {
@Id private String id;
private String Address;

@DBRef
private Person person;
}
```

PersonRespository.java

```
public interface PersonRespository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String> {
Mono<Person> findByName(String name);
}
```

PersonDetailsRespository.java

```
public interface PersonDetailsRespository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<PersonDetails, String> {    
}
```

While running this application the above said exception occurs and I can see that its using the mongodb driver version mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar.
I've noticed that it has problem with @DBref on Person class in PersonDetails.java, If I comment the following line from Application then it works

```
personDetails.setPerson(personRespository.findByName("Jitender").block());
```

Thanks in advance.
Jitender

Comment: The reactive API does not support DBRefs. References need to be resolved sooner or later and there's no API for that to do that.

Comment: Friends, I've got resolved the issue, This problem was with spring boot version that I was using, The issue is occurring with springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M2' where as If I use version M6 it got rectified e.g. springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'.  Thanks